# MFC Paint value without fillsolidrect function

Tags: c++, mfc

[image]

As above image, the background image is using CDC to paint, image is resource image item, otherwise will never repaint.

Now, I will repaint the value on background image, using cclientdc to paint,

but the value will recover, when I using setbackmode(TRANSPARENT).

so I using CRect FillSolidRect to paint the white background,

how do I repaint the value without using the white background.

### value

```
CClientDC dc(this);

dc.SelectObject(&fontTextMode);

dc.TextOutW(rectClient.right - 100,
                rectClient.bottom - 100,
                _T("Picture"),
                8);

for(int i=0; i< GetRealTestPoint(); i ++)
{
dc.SetTextColor(RealArray.GetAt(i).GetCurveColor());

        dc.FillSolidRect(sRealPictureMode.aryRectData[i], RGB(255,255,255));

        dc.SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT);

        strOutput.Format(_T("%s"), 
            RealArray[i].GetCurveName());
        dc.DrawText(strOutput, sRealPictureMode.aryRectName[i], DT_LEFT);

        if(abs(fTestAvgTemp - RealArray[i].GetCurrentData()) <= 5 && i < GetRealTestPoint())
        {
            strOutput.Format(_T("%.2f (%.2f)"), 
                RealArray[i].GetCurrentData(), fTestAvgTemp - RealArray[i].GetCurrentData());
        } else {
            strOutput.Format(_T("%.2f"), 
                RealArray[i].GetCurrentData());
        }
        if (i < 15)
        {
            if ((fTestAvgTemp + fTestTolerateTemp) > RealArray[i].GetCurrentData() &&
                (fTestAvgTemp - fTestTolerateTemp) < RealArray[i].GetCurrentData())
            {
                dc.SetTextColor(RGB(0, 255, 0));
            }
            else
            {
                dc.SetTextColor(RGB(255, 0, 0));
            }
        } 
        else
        {
            dc.SetTextColor(RGB(0, 0, 0));
        }

        dc.TextOutW(sRealPictureMode.aryRectData[i].left,
                    sRealPictureMode.aryRectData[i].top,
                    strOutput,
                    strOutput.GetLength());
        //sRealPictureMode.aryStcData[i]->SetWindowTextW(strOutput);
    }
    ReleaseDC(&dc);
```

### paint background (the code will paint once)

```
CBitmap bmp;
int bmWidth = 0;
int bmHeight = 0;

BITMAP bm;

// 計算圖片長寬
if(nSelPic == RECORD_NINE_TEST_POINT)
{
    bmp.LoadBitmapW(IDB_BITMAP_RECORD_NINE_TEST);
}

if(nSelPic == RECORD_FIFTEEN_TEST_POINT)
{
    bmp.LoadBitmapW(IDB_BITMAP_RECORD_FIFTEEN_TEST);
}

bmp.GetBitmap( &bm );
bmWidth = bm.bmWidth;
bmHeight = bm.bmHeight;

CClientDC dc(this);

dc.FillSolidRect(sRealtimeRect.rectCurve, RGB(255, 255, 255));

dc.Rectangle(sRealtimeRect.rectCurve.left,
    sRealtimeRect.rectCurve.top,
    bmWidth,
    bmHeight);

/*CBrush brush(&bmp);
dc.FillRect(CRect(sRealtimeRect.rectCurve.left,
sRealtimeRect.rectCurve.top,
sRealtimeRect.rectCurve.Width(),
sRealtimeRect.rectCurve.Height()),
&brush);*/
CDC dcMem;
if(dcMem.m_hDC == NULL) dcMem.CreateCompatibleDC(&dc);
// select the source bitmao into the memory DC
CBitmap* pOldBitmap = (CBitmap*)dcMem.SelectObject(&bmp);
// get the bitmap data
BITMAP bbmp = {0};
bmp.GetBitmap(&bbmp);
// transfer the bitmap into paint DC using a transparent color  
dc.TransparentBlt(sRealtimeRect.rectCurve.left, sRealtimeRect.rectCurve.top, bmWidth, bmHeight, // destination coordinates and sizes
    &dcMem,                            // source DC
    0, 0, bmWidth, bmHeight,   // source coordinates and sizes
    RGB(0, 0, 0));                   // transparent color
// restore DC / free GDI objects 
dcMem.SelectObject(pOldBitmap);
pOldBitmap = NULL;
```

I change the code as follow

```
//dc.FillSolidRect(sRealPictureMode.aryRectData[i], RGB(255,255,255));

UpdateWindow();

dc.SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT);
//dc.SetBkColor(GetSysColor(COLOR_WINDOWTEXT));
```

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nO06m.png)

Comment: Did you mean `SetBkMode()`?

Comment: yes , CClientDC dc(this);dc.SetTextColor(RGB(...));dc.FillSolidRect(RECT, RGB(255,255,255));dc.SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT);

Comment: You probably need to post the code that is relevant to the question so that people will get an idea of what is wrong.

Comment: the code show on the website http://pastebin.com/index/Ay1ZEq8V

Comment: `dc.FillSolidRect(sRealPictureMode.aryRectData[i], RGB(255,255,255));` you are explicitly filling the background rectangle area of the text with white. why don't you remove that?

Comment: Remove this, It will repaint value on the same rect area.

Comment: can you create a sample project to reproduce the problem? like a dialog with an image and one control... or what kind of window is that?

Comment: You are rendering at the wrong time, i.e. outside the `WM_PAINT` handler (`OnPaint` in MFC). The use of the `CClientDC` class is a strong indication for that. You need to understand the rules first, before you can start to break them. In other words: Learn how a Windows API/MFC application normally performs its rendering. See [Painting the Window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381401.aspx) for a short introduction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is: you have a composed scene with background image and a transparently rendered text on top; you want to change the text. So - you need to erase the previously rendered text first.

There are two ways to do that:

1. Before you call `TextOut()`, invalidate the bounding rectangle for that label and enforce the immediate painting of the background by calling `UpdateWindow()`.
2. The same can be achieved by creating transparent windows for each labels and simply updating their text.